# Hibernate Validator Class-Level constraints in the Constraints-Mappings file

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, validation

I am using the constraints-mappings XML for my bean validation.  I have several custom constraints that work fine, and groupings as well.  But I have looked rather exhaustively and I can't find how to set a Class-Level constraint in the mappings XML specifically.  Using annotations it's straightforward but if anyone has some insight on how to do this through the XML it would be greatly appreciated.  Here is an example of what I'm looking at:

```
<bean
    class="SearchRequestTO"
    ignore-annotations="false">
    <constraint annotation="service.constraints.ValidSearch"> <!--where can i put you?-->
      <field
        name="name">
        <valid />
      </field>
      <field
        name="birthDate">
        <valid />
      </field>
      <field
        name="phoneNumber">
        <valid />
      </field>
      <field
        name="emailAddress">
        <valid />
      </field>
      <field
        name="accountId">
        <valid />
      </field>
      <field
        name="role">
        <valid />
      </field>
    </constraint>
  </bean>
```

I don't need field level validation for this specific request but I do want to know if at least one of them has been populated which requires looking at the entire bean.  I already have a custom constraint and validator set up to handle this scenario...but I can't seem to get my XML to ever recognize my constraint annotation statement when outside of a field.  I have tried variations of the class tag to no avail.  Again, any assistance would be greatly appreciated.                             -Trax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I just needed to sleep on it.  Here is the working xml:

```
<bean
  class="SearchRequestTO"
  ignore-annotations="false">
    <class
      ignore-annotations="false">
      <constraint 
        annotation="service.constraints.ValidSearch">
      </constraint>
    </class>
    <field
      name="name">
      <valid />
    </field>
    <field
      name="birthDate">
      <valid />
    </field>
    <field
      name="phoneNumber">
      <valid />
    </field>
    <field
      name="emailAddress">
      <valid />
    </field>
    <field
      name="accountId">
      <valid />
    </field>
    <field
      name="role">
      <valid />
    </field>
  </constraint>
</bean>
```

Hopefully this will help someone else in the future.

Comment: For parameter we need to add element tag.

<constraint  annotation="com.mycompany.test.camel.spring.BothNotNull">
        <element name="fieldName">manufacturer</element>
        <element name="dependFieldName">licensePlate</element>
       </constraint>

Comment: @UmairSaleem - I'm not sure if that was a question, basically the syntax is identical to field validators but using the class tags.